# Cannot use the usb wireless card in virtualbox host:OSX guest:BT5

Tags: usb, virtualbox, wireless, backtrack-linux

i have try many solutions in internet and all solutions does not work to me. i set the usb filter of usb setting in virtual box, but it keep to pop-up error for me.

Here is the errors:

**Failed to attach the USB device Ralink 54M.USB....... [0001] to the virtual machine BT5.**

USB device 'Ralink 54M.USB.......' with UUID {ID} is in use by someone else.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: HostUSBDevice 
Interface: IHostUSBDevice 
 
Callee: IConsole

can someone help me?

thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extensions for Ralink are not allowing VirtualBox to attach to it. I found out that the Ralink wireless utility or the driver won't release it to the guest OS on VirtualBox. I deleted the kext (making sure I backed it up first) and rebooted. Now the VirtualBox guest OS (bt5 r3 in my case) sees it under lsusb after recompiling the driver for it, using modprobe rt5370sta, and blacklisting the other rt2x00 and rt2800.